# v4l2loopback "format not support" error in OBS Studio

Tags: v4l2loopback, obs-studio

I keep getting a weird error in OBS Studio while trying to enable my virtual camera, "format not support". This is after installing packages in Manjaro 19.0.2:

```
yay -S dkms linux56-headers
yay -S obs-v4l2sink v4l2loopback-dkms
```

Is this a OBS issue or a v4l2loopback one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. I forgot to run `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`. It enables it I think.

Comment: please accept your answer, so it doesn't show up as unresolved any longer.

Comment: If that was not enough, [here are more solutions](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/issues/5).

Answer (score 2):

Some stuff that help me figure out a similar issue:

Note that this issue can also arise from a video device that is not available e.g.
/dev/video1 when there is no active device /dev/video1 changing to another device e.g. /dev/video0 may resolve this error

list devices with:

`ls /dev | grep video`

you may be able to make additional devices available when you load the kernel module:

`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2`

See also:

https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/issues/5

Comment: as suggested, I just needed to switch to another device, `/dev/video2` in my case